# Firebase functions v 1.0: Alternative of DeltaSnapshot.changed() after v 1.0

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Before version 1.0 I was using `DeltaSnapshot.changed()` to check in my database functions if the data is changed under the incoming data. 
But now after upgrading to v 1.0 the method is not available any more.
Is there any other way to replicate this functionality?.

One way is to use the `before` and `after` and the loop children under the node which I need to check for changes.
Is there any better way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer we need to create our own method to have the functionality of changed check. So here is a helper, for object comparison at a given **relative path**(not absolute path from root /) in the event data.

```js
'use strict';
let _ = require('lodash');

/**
 *
 * @param data Change<DataSnapshot> object received in the event.
 * @param path Relative path in the data object received in the function.
 * @returns {boolean} return true if there is a change in data of before and
 * after snapshot , false if the values are identical
 */
function isChanged(data, path) {
    let before = data.before.child(path);
    let after = data.after.child(path);
    if (before.exists() && !after.exists() ||
        !before.exists() && after.exists()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return !_.isEqual(before.val(), after.val());
    }
}


module.exports = {
    isChanged
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way.  The `before` and `after` fields are your only indication of what changed during write or update events.

Answer (score 1):

You'll indeed have to do you own comparison between the before and after data to see what has changed.

```
if (change.after.val().valToCompare !== change.before.val().valToCompare) {
    << your code here >>
}
```